# I did not understand how this code exectuded in MS Visual C++ compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

```
void fn(int a[3])
{
    a[5]=5;
}

int main()
{
    int A[10] = {0};
    cout<<A[5]<<endl;
    fn(A);
    cout<<A[5]<<endl;
}
```

For the first print statement I got A[5]=0 and for the second time A[5]=5. How does this code actually work ?

Comment: What part of this doesn't behave as you expected?

Comment: Arrays are passed as a pointer and not as an array by value. i.e they are not copied when passed to a function.

Comment: How can we pass argument A to a fn(int a[3]) ? i.e Does it not behave something like this int a[3] = &A[0] ??

Comment: I know that it is passed as a pointer! I have edited my above comment!

Comment: @srinivasprabhu 
The argument in the function prototype is just a pointer in reality where the address of A is stored.. so he gets the address and manipulates the element at location 5.

Comment: @nimish that was not my question !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ array from programmer's view is *almost* equal to the pointer to its first element. In case of arrays passed by parameter, they are *equal*. If you imagine it this way, you pass the pointer to an array to function, then modify its sixth element (still the original!), and then display it.

Your code is equal to:

```
void fn2(int * a)
{
    *(a + 5) = 5;
}

(...)

fn(&(A[0]));
```

---

**Side note** The difference in statically allocated and dynamically allocated arrays can be seen while playing around with local variables:

```
int a[5];
int * p;

printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(p));
```

Comment: The code is *exactly* equal to that.

Comment: So writing int a[3] does not matter ?

Comment: It does. C++ treats dynamically and statically allocated arrays a little bit different. For instance, you can pass statically allocated array by parameter (eg. int[6]), but not dynamically alocated (eg. int[] - you have to use pointer instead).

Comment: @Spook: I'm not sure what you mean by your above comment, but it doesn't sound right!

Comment: When you pass statically allocated array as parameter, C++ *knows*, that it's an array (even sizeof will behave correctly). If you dynamically allocate an array, you can only pass it by pointer and sizeof() will show only size of the first element. This is core difference between my code and OP's and this is why I wrote "almost" and not "exactly".

Comment: @Spook: Arrays are *always* converted to pointer-to-first element when passed as args to a function (unless the function takes an array by reference).  So the OP's code is **exactly** identical to your code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Another example. You can easily exceed bounds of dynamically allocated array, but if you try to do so with statically allocated array, compiler will emit warning C4789 (VS). Again: C++ compiler sees difference between int[3], which is a statically allocated array and int * which is a pointer-to-int (possibly an array).

Comment: @Spook: It's also trivial to exceed the bounds of a static array in a way that the compiler can't detect.

Comment: @Spook: There is no difference between `int[3]` and `int*` in the context of a function prototype.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If so, call sizeof() on the parameter and check if there is really no difference.

Comment: @Spook: See e.g. http://ideone.com/sj0sAM.

Comment: Even in fn() if I change a[5]=5 to a[12]=6 and print a[12] in main everything is working fine even if it is outside the bounds !!!

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. There *is* a difference in local variables. There seems not to be one while passing arrays by parameters. I've edited the answer to reflect the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You code:

```
void fn(int a[3])
{
    a[5]=5;
}
```

Is equivalent to code:

```
void fn(int* a)
{
    a[5]=5;
}
```

Fortunately you can check it by  by compile your code with `-S` option to gcc (or g++).
**You will get same assembly output for Both:** (output file will be with `.s` extension)

```
fn:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax    // base address assign to eax register.
    addl    $20, %eax        // a[5] , because 5*4 = 20, so eax = eax + 20
    movl    $5, (%eax)       // this is =5 , (%eax) = 5
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .size   fn, .-fn
    .section    .rodata
```

Both Code use only base address pass to the `fu()` function.

<sub>there is nothing about size 3 of argument</sub>

Comment: This question requires *standard* proof, not practical proof.

Comment: "there is nothing about size 3 of argument" - but only in case of *this particular code*. Try to call sizeof() on int* and int[3].

Comment: @Spook  and Griwes Ok! I agree with both of you, OP can consider it if he like.

Comment: No concrete answers yet !!

Comment: And I thought it would be helpful in some way!

Comment: And what concrete answers would you expect? Maybe you should state more clearly, what do you want to know?

Comment: You said "Ok, I stand corrected. There is a difference in local variables. There seems not to be one while passing arrays by parameters." Is it defined in the C++ standard ?

Comment: @srinivasprabhu Have you got your answer?

Comment: @Spook I tried with `sizeof()` for both `int* and int[3]` still same code!!..II even myself bit unclear at this point.

Comment: Read my answer. sizeof() will return different result for a local variable. For a parameter it'll always return the same value. All I want to say is that generically int[3] and int * are *different* beings even when passing by a parameter changes them both to int *.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass the address of A to change the array itself:

```
fn(int **A)
```

Comment: No, you cannot change the address of an array.